# How do I make my pc speaker beep in WSL?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I make ring the bell from command line using WSL (2)?

I tried:

```
beep
echo -ne '\007'
echo -e "\a"
```

I have `set bellstyle none` in /etc/inputrc.

Using Ubuntu 18.04 image.

Comment: Uhh why did you `set bellstyle none` if you want the bell to ring? echoing the bell character in my WSL produces the default windows "ding"

Comment: I don't want the shell to beep all the time, it is super annoying and should be turned off by default IMO. Though I would like to start a long lasting process and then play a sound, so I know when it is finished and don't have to check visually all the time. E.g. I can go read something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In WSL Ubuntu or Alpine with default path setup, you can depend on .net's [Console.Beep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=net-5.0) method:

```bsh
powershell.exe '[console]::beep(261.6,700)'
```

It makes a handy alias for `etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
alias bloop="powershell.exe '[console]::beep(261.6,700)'"
```

Define a helper function to create multiple tones:

```bsh
_beep () {
  powershell.exe "[console]::beep($1,$2)"
}

alias bleep="_beep 1000 800"  # A strong bleep (for profanity)
alias  beep="_beep 2000 300"  # Quick yet noticeable beep
alias  blip="_beep 4000  80"  # A less distracting blip
```

Example: Blip on success, but bleep on failure:

```
make && blip || bleep
```

Comment: If PATH is broken, it might be due to these ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#interop), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop)) WSL settings.

In a pinch, adding  `/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/` to the path may fix the issue

Comment: It works ! :-).